# "WebClient.DownloadFile" throws an error when I pass arguments to it but works fine if I hardcode the values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# exe that uses .NET 4.6.1 framework. I launch this exe from a C++ exe as that is the requirement. It worked before but it suddenly stopped working the way it was supposed to.
I launch the exe with 5 parameters. I checked the value and the length of the arguments received, they all appear to be correct when the C# exe receives it but when it comes to the `DownloadFile` method it seems to throw an exception.
On the other hand, if I hardcode the values or run the exe in the command prompt and pass the arguments to it seems to work fine.
As soon as launch it from the C++ exe it writes this from the stack trace to the log that I'm printing it into

> username is: abc uname length is: 3| password is: abc@123 pass length
> is: 7| patch download from path is: \10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch
> testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip FileToDownload length is: 60| patch
> download to path is: E:\Test\Patch.zip localDestinationFilePath length
> is: 17
>
> System.Net.WebException Exception in DownloadPFile(
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
> at
> IPMPlusAlternatePatchDownloader.IPMPlusPatchDownloader.DownloadPFile(String userName, String password, String FileToDownload, String localDestinationFilePath)

Here is the code I'm using

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     PacthDownload.DownloadPFile(args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
}
private void DownloadFileShareAndFTP(string userName, string password, string FileToDownload, string localDestinationFilePath)
{
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            client.DownloadFile(FileToDownload, localDestinationFilePath);
}
```

Here is how it looks when I hardcode the values instead of getting them from the arguments

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          PacthDownload.DownloadFileShareAndFTP("abc", "abc@123",@"\\10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip", @"E:\Test\Patch.zip");
         //PacthDownload.DownloadPFile(args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]);
    }
    private void DownloadFileShareAndFTP(string userName, string password, string FileToDownload, string localDestinationFilePath)
    {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                client.DownloadFile(FileToDownload, localDestinationFilePath);
    }
```

> username is: abc uname length is: 3| password is: abc@123 pass length
> is: 7| patch download from path is: \10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch
> testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip FileToDownload length is: 60| patch
> download to path is: E:\Test\Patch.zip localDestinationFilePath length
> is: 17
>
> DownloadPFile EOF

the length is those of the arguments, not the values I hardcoded.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks like once the file is downloaded but for some reason it only

[image: 1]

I'm using visual studio 2017 for this.
I have removed the log statements from the code while adding it here so as to make it look cleaner.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you running from inside VS?  Inside VS you may not have Admin privilege's.  Try starting VS by right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Or run the exe from outside VS.

Comment: Please show screenshots of: it working perfectly with hard coded values. It failing when variables are used. A shot proving the variables are the exact same type of and number of and values of, as the hard coded version

Comment: @jdweng As mentioned I'm running it from a separate C++ exe but running it from visual studio directly works perfectly well too. It's only when I run it from the C++ exe that this issue occurs and yes I made sure the C++ exe launching my C# exe has all the necessary privileges.

Comment: Is it the same exe?  You may have more than one version of exe like in debug and release folders.

Comment: Nope, it's just the one Release exe I made sure to delete the rest.

Comment: @CaiusJard Jard I have added the Image of it working properly and I have also added what I receive in the arguments in the c# exe along with their length.

Comment: Can you show the command line where you start your program?

Comment: Also, this doesn't look correct: ` \10`, shouldn't you pass two backslashes here?

Comment: @Lasse V Karlsen I start it from within a C++ program, not the command line but if you want to see the command line start I can do that too. Also the 2 backslashes are necessary or else it wont work since that the exact path of the share folder.

Comment: Lasse is saying the hardcoded string `@"\\10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip"` and a dump of command line arg `\10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip` are different strings. I agree

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Argument your receive which contains the path this one `"patch download from path is: \10.1.1.119\Backup_share\patch testing\Skype-8.81.0.268.zip"` doesn't seem to contain any escape sequences for the characters for the "\" character which is probably why you're receiving the exception. Add an extra "\" after every "\" character that should fix it.